# How can a (angular) custom element tell if a <slot> is used

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I have this custom element with a couple of named slots. Depending on some state, one of the slots is shown. So assume that the custom element looks like

```html
<slot></slot>
<slot name="small"></slot>
<slot name="medium"></slot>
<slot name="large"></slot>
```

So, this component is used like this

```html
<p>default</p>
<div slot="small"><p>small</p></div>
<div slot="medium"><p>medium</p></div>
<div slot="large"><p>large</p></div>
```

Basically if the state of the custom element is `medium` it will show the `medium` slot. But, if the medium slot is not used/defined it should show the default slot. Is something like this possible, how can I detect if a slot is used?

Comment: Note that this is impossible example code, because custom elements don't allow tags without hyphens in them. Once you give them a real tag name, they'll act identically to regular HTML elements, and you'd check for "whether something is used" in the same way as if they were `div` or `p` or anything else.

Comment: thnx, I've updated the example to make it valid. But when shadowDom is enabled I noticed that the div is not inside the shadow dom or slot, so if you query inside the custom element for `[name=small]` you'll find nothing. I'll try to make an online example!

Comment: The shadow dom is "a black box" in the same way you can't queryselect the audio or video element's play controls. The idea of shadow dom is that that's private, off limits markup that lets you, the element designer, model what you need, but to everything else on the page all they get is your element, and its attributes, and that's it. They should not need to query inside your element. But what they _could_ do is _ask_ your element to do something by you declaring API functions at attribute monitoring so that your element can changes its internal state based on function calls and attr values.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Your statement is only correct for  **{mode:"closed"}** shadowDOM https://hayatoito.github.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#a-closed-shadow-root

Comment: In my case I have an "@angular/elements" custom component, which has shadowdom enabled. So, it is its own shadowdom I'm querying

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman on a technical level, yes, but on a conceptual level, no. Custom elements are meant to be as functional as any other html element, so whatever it needs to do internally should not be something other parts of the page can try to mess with. They get to set attributes and call API functions, but not access the shadow DOM. However, it turns out that this question is about a custom element accessing _its own DOM_ so maybe the post can be rewritten to be clear about that, and show a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that you can check if a slot has elements. Just do

```
element.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot[name=small]').assignedElements()[0];
```

Comment: but nothing on-page should _ever_ reach into another element's shadow dom. They should not need to know anything other than the public API you've set up for your element.

Comment: its not another shadowdom, it is its own shadowdom. I'm using @angular/elements to create custom components and I think that this is the only way to query the shadowdom

Comment: ah, that's a very different matter and I _highly_ encourage you to update your post to make this abundantly clear with a minimal example (with most of your custom element removed) that demonstrates what you're talking about, in that case.